# using foundation section's with php

Tags: php, mysql, css, sql, zurb-foundation

I am using the sections feature in the Foundation framework, 
"http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html#panel2".

My website is for a soccer club where I have a bunch of teams in a database table named "team". 
The team table has the following columns:
`team_id`,`team_name`.

I also have a table named "players".

The players table has the following columns:
`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`team_id`.

I want to make a section for each team where the tab is labeled the "team_name" from the "team" table, and the content of that section is all players on that team and will list all player names in that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, then you can just get the team id and then use:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `team_id`='7';
```

With "7" being an example id. Alternately you can have it all in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` t1 INNER JOIN `teams` t2 ON t2.team_name = 'example' AND t1.team_id = t2.team_id;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `players` t1, `teams` t2 WHERE t2.team_name = 'example' AND t1.team_id = t2.team_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I through this up: 
http://nicholasskearney.com/new%20coast/team.php
See how for each player they have their own tab?

Comment: I do see that, but what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I through this up: 
http://nicholasskearney.com/new%20coast/team.php
See how for each player they have their own tab?
'<div class="section-container auto" data-section>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM team, members WHERE team.team_id =members.team_id") or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo '<section>
<p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">'.$row['team_name'].'</a></p>
<div class="content" data-section-content>
<div class="row"> 
'.$row['first_name'],$row['last_name'].'
</div></div>         </section>';} 
?></div>
'

Comment: How do I get it so each team has only one tab and fill that tab's section with all the players on that team?
-sorry about lumping the code I dont know how to separate it in my comments:(

Comment: Get an array of the team ids, and then the table for players, and just sort the table in php via the team id.

Comment: OK thanks for help ill try that and get back if i have anymore questions. First time poster, glad I did very impressed with quickness of reply. Thank you.

Comment: My variable $child holds my array items(all the team's id) , how do I use the $child variable I created to work inside my mysql statement "WHERE id =  $child"? 

 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members 
WHERE id =  $child") 
or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo '<td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>'; 
}